# OroCommerce: How to add new product unit?

Tags: orocommerce

For some strange reason in so very configurable OroCommerce there is no ability to manage product units and the only few words [doc says](https://doc.oroinc.com/user/back-office/products/products/product-units/#user-guide-products-product-units-in-use) that its possible to add units via web api. I need to add "days" units and best if do it in code via migration. Is it enough just to make migration like

```sql
INSERT INTO `oro_product_unit` (`code`, `default_precision`) VALUES ('day', '0');
```

and add tranlation messages like

```yaml
oro.product_unit.day.label.full: day
oro.product.product_unit.day.label.full: day
```

or need to do smth else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Product units may be loaded to the database using the data fixtures, like this one that loads default units:
https://github.com/oroinc/orocommerce/blob/4.2.1/src/Oro/Bundle/ProductBundle/Migrations/Data/ORM/LoadProductUnitData.php#L47-L52

In addition, you have to provide translations for the new unit, but there are more messages then you specified in the question:
https://github.com/oroinc/orocommerce/blob/ad94fe9bd63db28eae7d4a73743a4cada4f49080/src/Oro/Bundle/ProductBundle/Resources/translations/jsmessages.en.yml#L26-L35